# /Israel.java:16: error: '.class' expected

Tags: java, java-util-scanner, javascript-import

**¡HOLA¡ Soy estudiante de preparatoria y pues soy nuevo en esto del mundo de la programación, el caso es que el profesor puso esto de examen.**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí])

**y bueno yo realice esto...**

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExamenIsrael{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        String cadena;
        
        int sueldo;
        
        for(int x=0; x<=0; x++){
            System.out.println ("Escriba su nombre:");
            cadena = sc.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println ("Escriba su Tipo de contrato, 1= CONFIANZA 2= SINDICALIZADO");
            cadena = sc.nextLine();
            if (cadena.equals ("1")){
                System.out.println (int = ("Escriba su sueldo"));
                if(sueldo <10000){
                    System.out.println ("SUELDO MENSUAL ES" + (sueldo * 0.9));
                    System.out.println ("IMMS ES" + (sueldo * 0.12));
                    System.out.println ("SAR ES" + (sueldo * 0.2 ));
                    System.out.println ("INFONAVIT" + (sueldo * 0.5));
                    System.out.println ("CUOTA SINDICAL" + (sueldo * 0.2));
                }
            }else{
                if(cadena.equals ("2")){
                    System.out.println (int = ("Escriba su sueldo"));
                    if (sueldo <10000){
                    System.out.println ("SUELDO MENSUAL ES" + (sueldo * 0.9));
                    System.out.println ("IMMS ES" + (sueldo * 0.12));
                    System.out.println ("SAR ES" + (sueldo * 0.2 ));
                    System.out.println ("INFONAVIT" + (sueldo * 0.5));
                    System.out.println ("CUOTA SINDICAL" + (sueldo * 0));   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Y pues me salían estos errores...**

/ExamenIsrael.java:16: error: '.class' expected
System.out.println (int = ("Escriba su sueldo"));
^

**Ya me rendí, la fecha de entrega ya termino, y lo entregue con los dos errores, sin embargo me llama la curiosidad saber cual fue el error que cometí para que en un futuro no vuelva a cometerlo, si me podrían ayudar a corregirlo se los agradecería mucho..**

Answer (score 0):

Los errores que salen son porque 2 veces estas tratando de convertir texto a un entero de forma incorrecta ademas de que es texto no numérico.

1. En Java para convertir una cadena de texto a un numero entero se usa `Integer.parseInt(text);` que es la forma correcta.
2. La clase Scanner cuenta con métodos específicos para pedir entradas numéricas, dobles o flotantes.

La linea de código que te tira el error es esta:

```
System.out.println(int = ("Escriba su sueldo"));
```

Ahí estas convirtiendo el texto "Escriba su sueldo" a un numero, lo que lanza un error ya que la cadena contiene caracteres no numéricos, lo que tendrías que hacer es llamar al `Scanner`, pedir una entrada numérica por teclado y guardarlo en la variable sueldo, algo así.

```
System.out.println("Escriba su sueldo");
sueldo = sc.nextInt();
if(...)
```

O pedir un texto, `sc.nextLine()` y utilizando `Integer.parseInt(cadena)` convertirlo en un numero para guardarlo en sueldo.

Comment: Espero que la nota del examen te la pongan a ti entonces, y no a él. *`public class ExamenIsrael`*. Con semejante error demuestra mucha falta de base. Aprobar un examen y arrastrar un déficit de conocimientos es peor que suspender.